# How to use JSON returned data inside Body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to store JSON result in some variable and then i want to use that variable inside BODY of html.

Below is my code in which i am getting nothing in "test" alert.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello jQuery</title>  
                  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">
   var msg;   
   $(document).ready(function () {  
   var msg1;
       $.ajax({          
           url: "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"
            //var msg2;
       }).then(function(data) {
          json_list = data.id;
          msg= data.id;
          msg1= data.id;
           var $temp = $('.class1').append(data.content);
          //alert($temp);
          //msg2= data.id;
          /* $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);  */
          alert("Inside AJAX "+data.content);
          $('#content').html(data.content);
          //msg=$('#content').html();
          //return msg;
            // $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);*/
           // alert(msg);
          
         });
       
      
   });
  </script>
  <div  id="content"></div>
  <div class="class1">
  
 </div>
  <script>  
  var test1=$('#content').contents();   
   alert("Test Result -- " +test1);
   </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Can you pls suggest me how i can achieve this ?

I want to store JSON value in test1 variable (in BOLD).

Let me know if any further info required.

Comment: you return data in json..?

Comment: Are you sure you're returning JSON data?

Comment: I have used sample REST which will return below JSON string
{"id":182834,"content":"Hello, World!"}

then i am fetching value from key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the data into parseJSON(data) and than use

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
                        var msg1;
                       $.ajax({          
                           url: "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"
                                //var msg2;
                       }).then(function(data) {
                           // see here i change.
                                var data_json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                                json_list = data_json.id;
                                //bellow is function.
                                  passinganotherscript(json_list);

                                msg= data_json.id;
                                msg1= data_json.id;
                                 var $temp = $('.class1').append(data_json.content);

                                $('#content').html(data_json.content);

                         });

function passinganotherscript(data){
      //here you are able to access your value of data.
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: But how i will store the value of "data_json.id" inside BODY area ?

Comment: @AryanSingh : can just show me what you are returning or json response..? so i will tell you..?

Comment: @AryanSingh : just keep in mind your returning id is like $data['id'] = 'whatever your value'; and echo json_encode($data);

Comment: JSON response (stored in data)
{"id":182834,"content":"Hello, World!"}

now i can fetch values from response data like data.id or data.content..

let me know if any further info required

Comment: @AryanSingh : i hope now you are getting

Comment: @Lalt -- Apology if my question is not clear to you...let me explain the issue...
inside $(document).... function i can use response data (like storing, printing e.t.c.) but as per my requirement, i need to have this response data available outside the $(document).... function.

Inside second script if i want to store the response result in any variable then it is returning as "undefined" (No value).

Comment: @AryanSingh : Check it out i have edited my answer for you and i hope  now this will help.

Comment: same response..undefined :(

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lalit..it works for me :)
Appreciate your help on this..you really save my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is not time travel.

Your code:

1. Sets up a document.ready event handler
2. Takes the content of `#content` and puts it in a variable and then alerts it.
3. (in response to the ready event firing) makes an Ajax request and sets up an event handler for when an HTTP response is received
4. (in response to the HTTP response) changes the contents of `#content`

By that stage the code that assigns the variable has already run. The code that alerts the value of that variable has already run.

If you want to do anything with that content, then do so **inside the success handler**.

Comment: I need that value for further processing..alert is just for logging purpose.

So there is no way to use that value ?

Comment: @AryanSingh — See the last line of the answer. Do the processing inside the success handler.

Comment: yes i understand but i need to use that result inside second <script> (outside the AJAX scope)

Comment: @AryanSingh — You can't. That code runs too soon. You have to wait until you have the response before you can do anything with that response.

Comment: @Quentin-- Yes that is the main issue for me..can you suggest any other way to achieve this ? because i need to invoke REST services and after that on the basis of response data (lat and long) i need to draw a google map..

Comment: Why can't you call a function to draw a Google map inside success handler?